# XML to CSV in PHP

Tags: php, xml, csv, fputcsv

I am trying to convert XML to CSV with the code below but it will only work if there is only one row. Multiple entries will only display the headers/column names.

This is what my XML looks like:

```
<Cars>
  <Type>B</Type>
  <Car>
    <Brand>Car1</Brand>
    <Model>M1</Model>
    <Year>2010</Year>
    <Age>9</Age>
    <Desciption>test</Desciption>
  </Car>
</Cars>


<Cars>
  <Type>B</Type>
  <Car>
    <Brand>Car2</Brand>
    <Model>M2</Model>
    <Year>2015</Year>
    <Age>4</Age>
    <Desciption>test</Desciption>
  </Car>
</Cars>
```

My code:

```
 $filexml='cars.xml';

  $cname=array();

  $cname[] = 'Brand';
  $cname[] = 'Model';
  $cname[] = 'Year';
  $cname[] = 'Age';
  $cname[] = 'Desciption';


  if (file_exists($filexml)) {
      $xml = simplexml_load_file($filexml); 
      $f = fopen('cars.csv', 'w') or die('Can\'t create .csv file, try again later.');
      fputcsv($f, $cname);

      foreach ($xml->Car as $Car) {
        fputcsv($f, get_object_vars($Car),',','"');
      } 

      fclose($f);

  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that your XML is actually valid (has a single root element) then a simplified view of the structure is this:

```
<document>
    <Cars>
       <Car>
          <Brand>Car1</Brand>
       </Car>
    </Cars>
    <Cars>
       <Car>
          <Brand>Car2</Brand>
       </Car>
    </Cars>
</document>
```

Note that there are multiple `Cars` nodes at the same level, but only one `Car` in each one.

When you load the XML, your initial PHP variable will represent the `<document>` element.

So you could access the first two brands by hand like this (the `(string)` gets the text content from the XML element):

- `(string)$xml->Cars[0]->Car->Brand`
- `(string)$xml->Cars[1]->Car->Brand`

To get all the brands, you need to loop over `$xml->Cars`:

```
foreach ( $xml->Cars as $CarsNode ) {
   $CarNode = $CarsNode->Car;
   $brand = (string)$CarNode->Brand;
}
```

From there, you can use your existing code to write a row to your CSV file.

Answer (score 2):

For each child node/tag you must use `__toString()` method.

Like that:

```
foreach ($xml->Car as $Car) {
    $row = [];
    foreach ($cname as $node) {
        // Here we address to the Car's child node with name from your array above
        $row[$node] = $Car->{$node}->__toString();
    }

    fputcsv($f, $row, ',' ,'"');
} 

fclose($f);
```

Comment: Oh, I see. Why in your XML-code you have 2 `<Cars>` blocks with one child in each one?

Comment: That is how it is structured since it is form of response from a certain page.

Comment: But that's not correct - in XML must be only one root-node. Or I don't understand you :) Maybe that helps: you must load not only `->Car` in one loop, but `->Cars->Car` because you have to of `Cars` nodes.

Comment: Already tried and does not work either. Is it possible to clean the XML format before converting it?

Comment: I think you can just wrap your xml string with one root-node (like `<root></root>`). Then, you can go for each `root->Cars->Car` as I write above. But first, of course, you must get xml-string from file (for wrapping) and use `simplexml_load_string` instead `simplexml_load_file`

Comment: I already added a root node and used simplexml_load_string and still not working.

Comment: I think my question this time should be about this line "you must get xml-string from file (for wrapping)", how should I do it?

Comment: Like this: http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/27384ae7d5910e2245a37ba2b60190310937c06e

Comment: Thanks man but still not working. File is not being read if the your code is used. Even column names are no longer written on the file. Also, root node was already added on my previous code. I've appended it in the XML file.